# Selecting a record in Dropdown should throw error based on value in the record

Tags: axapta, x++

HI I have a dropdown for a field in a form which shows records with each record having values (Name, Status).

Ex:: A1  Active

```
 A2  Active
 A3  Inactive
 A4  Active
 A5  Inactive
```

If i select A3 or A5 which are inactive i should get a warning/error saying you are selecting inactive value.

How can i acheive this? What is best way to acheive this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using validation?

Using `validateField` or `validateWrite` on the table or datasource you can test whether the chosen value is valid.

Also the `validate` method on the datasource or control could be used.

Search the Tables or Forms node of the AOT for thousands of examples.

Answer (score 0):

On the `FormDataSource` override the [`active`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/formdatasource.active.aspx) method. Reference to current record is by *datasource name*.

Comment: Can you explain little more. I didnt get that. Thanks in advance.